# How to change which ionicon is displayed upon menu toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I'm trying to do is have the 'menu-outline' ionicon display on my website, until it is clicked and the menu is toggled, where the 'close-outline' icon will replace it, and vice versa. I'm using jQuery.

I know you can toggle classes, but my ionicons are not defined by their classes, but by their names:

```
<a class="menu-button js-menu-button"><ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon></a>
```

My jQuery so far only toggles the menu but does nothing with the icon:

```
 $(".js-menu-button").click(function() {
    var nav = $(".js-main-nav");
    var icon = $(".js-menu-button ion-icon");
    /* appear and disappear */
    nav.slideToggle(200);
});
```

Is there any way I can toggle the name of the icon? Or is there another way to do this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle the name of the icon like this:

```
  $(".js-menu-button").click(function() {
     var nav = $(".js-main-nav");
     var icon = $(".js-menu-button ion-icon");
     if (icon.attr("name") == "menu-outline") {
        icon.attr("name", "close-outline");
     } 
     else {
        icon.attr("name", "menu-outline")
     }
     /* appear and disappear */
     nav.slideToggle(200);
  });
```

Another possibility is this:

```
 $(".js-menu-button").click(function() {
    var nav = $(".js-main-nav");
    var icon = $(".js-menu-button ion-icon");
    icon.attr('name', function(index, attribute){
       return attribute == "menu-outline" ? "close-outline" : "menu-outline";
    });
    /* appear and disappear */
    nav.slideToggle(200);
 });
```

Comment: its scary how this is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late, but I had the same situation in JavaScript. To solve the problem you create a class (example: 'toggle-mode') in side your ion-icon as in :

```
<ion-icon class="toggle-mode" name="moon-outline"> </ion-icon>
```

and then you can access/change your icon name easily (by toggle-mode.name) as in the following example:

```
toggleMode.name =
    toggleMode.name == "moon-outline" ? "sunny-outline" : "moon-outline";
```

In this example, I am toggling between 'sunny-outline' and 'moon-outline'.